# Using git merge --squash to merge develop into master when master was previously merged into develop?

Tags: git, version-control, merge

I have two branches. My master branch and my feature branch.

I'm developing on the feature branch and did several commits there and pushed them to the remote. From time to time I merged the master branch into my develop branch to make sure that I get the newest changes.

Now I'm done with developing on the develop branch and want to merge the develop branch into the master branch.

Ideally, I would like to squash all commits on the develop branch into one single commit. I guess I could do that with

```
git merge --squash
```

However, can I still do that when I merged master into develop from time to time?

Comment: Have you get the answer which help you solve the problem? If yes, you can mark it as answer. And it will help others who have similar questions.

Answer (score 3):

If you use `git merge develop --squash` to merge `develop` branch into `master`, it won’t squash commits to a commit on `develop` branch, but create a "merge commit" on master branch. Illustrate by below graphs:

Assume the original commit history is (before merging `develop` into `master`):

```
A---B---F---G   master
     \
  …---C---D---E   develop
```

After you execute `git merge develop --squash`, the new commit `H` as if you do a real merge the changes from `develop` branch into `master`.

```
A---B---F---G---H   master
     \
  …---C---D---E   develop
```

And of cause you can merge `master` into `develop` and then merge `develop` branch back into `master` branch. But it’s not a recommend way. You should **treat only one branch as the main branch** (such as  `master` branch as main branch). When the other branch (`develop`) has new features/changes, you just need to merge `develop` into `master` branch. When other new changes committed on `develop` branch later, you just need to merge `develop` branch into `master` branch from time to time.

And if you only want to squash commits on `develop` branch, you can use `git  rebase -i develop~n`, and then edit the commits you want to squash (change `drop` to `squash`) in interactive window.

Comment: A merge from master to develop is needed by most repos that have a lot of activity when "hotfixes" come into play. Your advice is mostly sound, but it is not an absolute. In the case of merging hotfixes from master to develop, one will wind up with an extra commit for the PR entry, but the actual code commit does not "re-merge" back since it already exists. It is merely a sync from master to dev (as it should be).

Answer (score 1):

You have merged `master` into `develop` from time to time - you mean to say you have updated the `master` branch and `develop` branch with the changes from `master` branch, in your local repo from time to time, correct?

In that case, when you do a `git checkout develop` and a `git log`, and *if you are the only person who has been working on this branch*, you should see only your commits till date - in which case you can directly do a `git merge --squash develop`, which will take all the commits made to `develop` branch and squash it into one.

*If you have other people working on this `develop` branch too*, and their commits are also in between yours, and you want to only squash your commits, then do a `git rebase -i`, where you can pick the commits you want to squash by replacing the word **'pick'** before the corresponding commits with **'squash'**.

Or, you can follow the first method listed [here](https://makandracards.com/makandra/527-squash-several-git-commits-into-a-single-commit).

> The easiest way to turn multiple commits in a feature branch into a
>   single commit is to reset the feature branch changes in the master and
>   commit again, this time - everything as one.

Comment: No, I merged master into develop. And if I do git log on the develop branch I see all the changes from the master and the develop branch.

Comment: @FischerLudrian alright - so you can still do `git rebase -i` and pick the commits you want to squash and do a single commit - is that okay?

Comment: @FischerLudrian I have updated my answer, hope this helps.

Comment: @FischerLudrian Did this solve your issue? If yes, please accept the answer by clicking on the check mark next to the answer